# Semantic UI dropdown allowAdditions - add to menu?

Tags: semantic-ui

I'm trying to use the `allowAdditions: true` setting on a single search selection dropdown, and it's behaving as expected, however I am trying to have it behave a little differently and cannot find any examples or documentation suggesting how it can be done if it's possible.

Right now, when I enter a new value, it simply sets the value of the hidden input and that's it. What I want, is to have it actually add that item to the menu and not just set the inputs value.

Alternatively, is there a callback that lets me know when a custom value has been added so I can handle the rest in javascript. I've tried the `onLabelCreate` callback, but I think this only works for a multi-select dropdown so it's never fired

**Edit**

OK so looks like this is a known bug https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/5759 but doesn't help with the callback issue.

For now as a **horrible** workaround, I've kept a list of the dropdown contents on page load, then when the `onChange` callback is fired, check to see if the newly selected value is present in the list. If not, then it adds a new menu item to the dropdown, selects it, and adds to the list of known items. Horribly hack but it works for now

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to the workaround you mention, in the `onChange()` callback you can check whether `$choice` (third parameter corresponding to the element) has class `addition`, like this:

```
$('.dropdown').dropdown({
    ignoreCase: true,
    allowAdditions: true,
    hideAdditions: false,
    onChange: function(value, text, $choice) {
        if ($choice.hasClass('addition')) {
            console.log(`adding ${value}`);
        }
    }
})
```